How to generate custom DKIM , DMARC and SPF records for my custom domain?
and how to do it via node js ?

Try a web search; these steps are documented in many places all over the web. This question is also off-topic here, as it's not about programming. Check the [help/on-topic].

@Robert I have searched but they are suggesting some online tool and others.
But i need to know how those records were created and their algorithm. I need to generate it on my own.
And additionally, i have implemented on my Node.js application using "smtp-server."
For the newly created smpt server, i need to add the DKIM, DMARC, and SPF records for sending emails programmatically.
Thanks for your feedback. :)

For SPF you need a DNS record at the domain that you use as senders domain when sending e-mails. The content of this record contains the IP-number of your SMTP server. This will allow for example G-mail to see that the owner of your domain has authorised your SMPT-server to send e-mails "on the domain owners behalf".
For DKIM you need a DNS record (same domain as above) that contains a public key of typically a rsa-sha256 key pair. You then setup your SMTP server to sign all outgoing e-mails using the private key in that pair. This will allow G-mail (among other things) to see that your domain has sent this e-mail, because no one else has the private key and could thus not have signed your e-mail.
For DMARC you need a DNS record (same domain as above) that tells all other mail servers what to do with e-mails that does not align with your SPF or your DKIM settings. Typically allow or reject.
You can read more details on the DNS format here:
[1] SPF: https://postmarkapp.com/guides/spf
[2] DKIM: https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dkim
[3] DMARK: https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dmarc
[4] Verify your setup: https://www.learndmarc.com/

Please refrain from answering off-topic questions. We don't want to encourage them.
